# How to implement arduino Uno shiftOut() in AVR C?

Tags: c, arduino, avr

I am trying to control an 8x8 led matrix using shift register 74hc595. In normal Arduino code, we use the `shiftOut()` function to write to the dataPin, but what I am having trouble trying out the same thing in AVR C. The only issue I am having is how to send the data to only the dataPin of the shift register, because if I use `PORTB |= data` everything in the port gets affected.

This is my code so far -

```
#define F_CPU 20000000L
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>

#define latchPinColumn 3
#define latchPinRow 2
#define clockPin 4
#define dataPin 5

//for looping
byte i, j;

//storing data
byte dataToSendColumn;
byte dataToSendRow;

int main()
{
  //enabling output pins
  DDRB |= (1 << dataPin);
  DDRB |= (1 << clockPin);
  DDRB |= (1 << latchPinColumn);
  DDRB |= (1 << latchPinRow);
  
  PORTB = 0x00; //setting everything to low
  
  while(1)
  {
    for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
      for(j=0; j<8; j++)
      {
        dataToSendColumn = (1<<i);
        dataToSendRow = (1<<j);
        
        PORTB = 0x00;   //setting everything to low
        shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, dataToSendColumn); //controlling the column
        PORTB |= (1 << latchPinColumn); //setting latch pin for led column to high
        PORTB ^= (1 << latchPinColumn); //setting latch pin for led column to low
        shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, dataToSendRow); //controlling the row
        PORTB |= (1 << latchPinRow); //setting latch pin for led row to high
        PORTB ^= (1 << latchPinRow); //setting latch pin for led column to low
        
      }
    }
  }
}

void shiftOut(int dataP, int clock, int val)
{
  //performing shiftOut in LSBFIRST method
  for(i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
    data = val & 0b00000001;
    PORTB |= data;
    PORTB ^= (1^=clock);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should provide your real attempt at `shiftOut`, the one that affects everything. The one you have won't even compile.

Comment: I have updated the code to what I wrote before submitting and as you can see I am affecting the entirety of PORTB, and I know that is wrong.

Comment: To set a pin low use &= ~(bitmask) not ^=(bitmask)

Comment: you have a some of language mistakes in bitwise operators.. i strongly recommend to study or Revision `C language` first ... you could practice on [Hacker Ranck](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/c?filters%5Bstatus%5D%5B%5D=unsolved&badge_type=c) to improve your selfe faster

Comment: @Delta_G I used XOR because I wanted to toggle the bit

Comment: No, you want to set the bit low.  Look at your comment.  It works for now cause you just set it high.  But it’s still the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### how arduino implement ShiftOut

```
void shiftOut(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val)
{
    uint8_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
        if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST)
            digitalWrite(dataPin, !!(val & (1 << i)) );
        else    
            digitalWrite(dataPin, !!(val & (1 << (7 - i))));
            
        digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);        
    }
}
```

### some note to helpe you in explanition of the code

1. **first of all** the type of `uint8_t` is just `char` Type in some place it there is somthing like this `typedef char uint8_t`
2. as Showen in **function signature** it Take 4 char as an argument

   - `data pin` the pin number that you conect the data on it
   - `clock pin` the pin number that you conect the clock on it
   - `bit Order` To choose which bit go first (*least significant bit go first or most significant bit go first*) and there are some definetions you could use For that `#define LSBFIRST 0` and `#define MSBFIRST 1`
   - `Val` the data you like shift it out on pins
3. the data `Val` is a `char` Type and Char type is just an **8 bit** so you will loop 8 time to get each bit in `val`
4. `1<<i` this is **shift left operator** it just will creat a musk of bits For examble if `i is equal 5` than that will creat binary like `0b00100000` and if `i is equal to 2` that will creat binary bits like `0b00000100`
5. `val & (1<<i)` ... the operator `&` is a **bitwise and opertor** this expration will give a non zero values if the i'th bit in `val` is `1` and will give zero if the i'th bit in `val` is Zero
6. the data will writen in shift Register if the clock pin go from High to low

### How to implrment it with your AVR

the implementation in AVR will be much similar to arduino implementation with a little bit difference ... you should notice that in arduino you access the pin just with a **pin number** and inside the Function used by arduino this **pin number** will be decoded into **port Number** (*PORTA,PORTB,..etc*) and **bit Number** inside that port

**important information** you need to know that the port is just an Regester in memory and that register is 8 bit width and you code access that Register with `Char pointer`

### the AVR Code FOR Shift out

```
// helper macros to make pin HIgh or low
#define  SET_PIN(port,pinNumber)  ( (port) |= (1<<pinNumber))
#define  CLEAR_PIN(port,pinNumber) ( (port) &=~(1<<pinNumber) )
// defention for Bits order
#define LSBFIRST 0
#define MSBFIRST 1

// pin information
typedef struct {
    volatile unsigned char * Port;
    char NUmber;
}Pin;

// function implementaiton
void shiftOut(Pin dataPin, Pin clockPin, char bitOrder, char val)
{
    char i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
        if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST){
            (val & (1 << i))?SET_PIN(*dataPin.Port,dataPin.NUmber):CLEAR_PIN(*dataPin.Port,dataPin.NUmber);
        }
        else{
            (val & (1 << (7 - i)))?SET_PIN(*dataPin.Port,dataPin.NUmber):CLEAR_PIN(*dataPin.Port,dataPin.NUmber);
        }

        // make a clockpin go from high to low
        SET_PIN(*clockPin.Port,clockPin.NUmber);
        CLEAR_PIN(*clockPin.Port,clockPin.NUmber);
    }
}
```

and use it inside main like this

```
void main(){
   //code ...
   // init section 
    Pin data = {&PORTB,4};
    Pin clock= {&PORTB,5};
    // make it output
    DDRB |=1<<4;
    DDRB |=1<<5;        
    //code ...
    while(1){
        // code ..
        // use when you need
        shiftOut(data,clock,LSBFIRST,9); // this will shift out 9(0b00001001) low bit will go first
        // code ...
    }   
        
}
```

this is a quick way ... you Could make it better if you have your own GPIO Drivers (General Purpose Input Output Driver) For set and clear PIns and make them input or output